# Timezone correction with daylight savings in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I don't have much knowledge regarding xslt process.

I need to automatically determine the time zone of Amsterdam/Europe with taking into consideration the summer time (GMT+1 or GMT+2).

[image: How to Automatically show if it's GMT+1 or GMT+2 of Amsterdam zone]

Could you please suggest/advise how to provide this information in an xslt file?

Many thanks!

Comment: So how does your input data look, is that a date (in which format?), solely your city/region, a date plus city/region? I think you will need to try to connect to a API over HTTP, like https://timezonedb.com/references/get-time-zone.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Yes the input data is a date , with format YYYY-MM-DDT hh:mm, but it doesn't precise if it's GMT+1 or otherwise. Could it be possible to pass this parameter to this xslt file from a java class?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51068765/252228, it seems XSLT/XPath 2 and later with the `format-dateTime` function provide a fifth argument to that function to adjust the display of the time zone information to a location/place, e.g. https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2Ch which displays `2018-01-01T10:00:00+01:00` as `2018-01-01T10:00:00 GMT+01:00` and `2018-06-01T10:00:00+01:00` as `2018-06-01T11:00:00 GMT+02:00` with location/place as `'Europe/Amsterdam'`. So if you are able to use XSLT 2 or 3 with e.g. Altova or Saxon you can use that approach.